How to install popular media codecs in Fedora 40?
I am using Fedora 40 with Gnome. I am somehow able to play mkv video files with vlc after installing its plugins but I want to install codecs in the system so that I could play videos with any player like Gnome videos or Haruna.
Tried rpmfusion and many other but idk if I missed something there, nothing worked. Can anyone guide me to get things working?
